# Apache NIFI - running https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi/ returning basic page with weird symbols

Tags: apache-nifi

Did anyone encounter below issue post installing Apache Nifi on Linux? I am able to start Nifi by running bin/nifi.sh start which returns below:
*Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /home/azureuser/nifi-1.16.1
Bootstrap Config File: /home/azureuser/nifi-1.16.1/conf/bootstrap.conf*

When checking the status i am getting below:
*Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
NiFi home: /home/azureuser/nifi-1.16.1
Bootstrap Config File: /home/azureuser/nifi-1.16.1/conf/bootstrap.conf
2022-08-20 18:59:57,126 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 39401, PID=4005*

But when running http://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi/ i am getting screen as per attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwc9g.png)

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. NIFI runs over HTTPS. Try going to the HTTPS page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to access NiFi Web UI with https

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi/
```

to turn off security you have to set this in `nifi.properties`

```
nifi.web.https.host=localhost
nifi.web.http.port=8080
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
```